# Image style settings for scaling an image

Tags: media

What settings can I use for the image style module that will make all thumbnails in a gallery  of a consistent width and height? Thus, if an image's width is smaller than the thumbnail width when scaled, the width of the thumbnail remains consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the *Scale and crop* option ? Go to `admin/config/media/image-styles/add` add a new style and then select *Scale and crop* with, for example, 100px width and height. This will produce some square thumbnail with 100px sides.
[image: scale and crop]